# Using relative URLs in <link rel="canonical" … />

Tags: google-search-console, rel-canonical

I just noticed that Google support's [Consolidate duplicate URLs - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) says:

> Use absolute paths rather than relative paths with the rel="canonical"
>   link element.
>
> Use this structure: https://www.example.com/dresses/green/greendresss.html
>   *Not* this structure: /dresses/green/greendress.html

I've always used simply the filename, without extension, as in:

```
public/Recipes/Mushy_Peas.xhtml:   <link rel="canonical" href="Mushy_Peas" />
```

without any obvious problem reported in Google's webmaster report pages, which reports:

> User-declared canonical
>   https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Recipes/Mushy_Peas

Using the stripped filename is a lot easier than entering the entire URL.

(Note that there aren't multiple URLs to the page, other than with/without the ".html" suffix.)

Is there any reason to change this (and a few hundred others) to be the full URL?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! You are fine. Googles point is to include the entire URL ***including*** the domain name otherwise the canonical link becomes useless in cases like if someone copies your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using a canonical URL is to establish the **specific URL** you want to rank for and therefore avoid duplicate content. If you use a relative URL as a canonical, multiple options can still be used.

Let's put an example, for the relative URL `/dresses/green/greendress.html` those would be the options:

- `http://example.com/dresses/green/greendress.html`
- `http://www.example.com/dresses/green/greendress.html`
- `https://example.com/dresses/green/greendress.html`
- `https://www.example.com/dresses/green/greendress.html`

So an absolute path is a must to make sure canonical works fine.